# Is Facebook an OpenID provider?

Tags: authentication, facebook, openid, openid-provider

Is Facebook an OpenID provider? I know they are an OpenID supporter but do they allow people to authenticate with other sites via OpenID with their Facebook credentials?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

No, they're not an OpenId provider. They use their own OpenID-like system called Facebook connect, which you can use to authenticate users on your site, among other features.

You can check it out here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Comment: They provide oAuth 2.0 as per @Ashley's comment

Comment: @Ashley … just to clarify David's comment for the clueless like me, OAuth is distinct from OpenID, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid#OpenID_vs._Pseudo-Authentication_using_OAuth , so they are still *not* an OpenID provider, far as I can tell.

Comment: Does this still hold true? I just wonder because Facebook is an option for sign in to stackexchange sites, but does that use OAuth rather than OpenID then (even though OpenID is mentioned in the info box next to it?

Comment: @MiikaL. Facebook does not support OpenID.  It does support OAuth 2.

Comment: you can also check in this blog mention how to achieve this https://developersandeep.blogspot.in/2017/03/oauth-authentication-google-facebook.html

Answer (score 12):

There is an unofficial Facebook OpenID Provider available at:

http://facebook-openid.appspot.com/

You can eaisly use it to log in any OpenID site with Facebook accounts.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea to me. It basically amounts to "hey, you can type your Facebook password into this site that isn't Facebook"

Answer (score 10):

Facebook is not an OpenID provider, they do however [allow OpenID login using Google accounts](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2009/05/18/facebook-supports-openid-for-automatic-login/).

OpenID provides a list of the most [popular providers](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/).

Comment: Actually, they allow OpenID login from virtually any OpenID Provider -- not just Google.  The news really got that detail wrong by highlighting Gmail as the only one.  But you still have to have a Facebook password. :(

Comment: It seems, like this function has been removed since 2009? Or is there still a way to use an OpenID provider to login to Facebook?

Comment: Link for _popular providers_ is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

OpenID is a decentralized authentication protocol. It allows users to be authenticated by co-operating sites using a third party service, eliminating the need for webmasters to provide their own login systems, and allowing users to log into multiple unrelated websites without having to have a separate identity and password for each.

Users create accounts by selecting an **OpenID identity provider**, and then use those accounts to sign onto any website which accepts OpenID authentication. [Here](https://openid.net/developers/certified/) is a list of OpenID providers.

Facebook neither use OpenID nor OAuth as instead of just offering credentials, Facebook wanted to offer friend access and dynamics to the privacy of the information that simply wasn’t possible with the other standards. With Facebook Connect, what we see are elements of both OpenID and OAuth. **Facebook Connect** can verify that you are who you say you are, and it can then provide access to your data once you’ve given it permission to do so.