# Create an own "OpenID-like system" Provider

Tags: authentication, openid, ruby-on-rails-3, openid-provider

I know that Facebook use their own OpenID-like system called "Facebook connect", which you can use to authenticate users on your site, among other features.

In my case I have multiple Ruby on Rails applications:

- users.example.com
- profiles.example.com
- photos.example.com
- ...

I would like to use 'users.example.com' as a *web service* that allows users to authenticate to all my other applications the same way as works "Facebook connect" or OpenID. In few words, **'users.example.com' must works as a "OpenID-like system"** for my applications in 'example.com'.

Can anyone give me tips and links to some useful resources?

*P.S.*: since I am a newbie in this matter, I do not know if I'm saying things that make sense. So someone could help me to understand (if I am wrong) ...

Comment: Does it need to an OpenID like system or can it be just standard OpenID? There are open source openid-provider scripts, and openid login scripts for most languages commonly used for web development.

Comment: I would like to implement a my own OpenID-like system as "Facebook connect".

Comment: I don't know about Facebook connect, but isn't it just an implementation of openid? You can restrict the allowed openid providers for login to just your own provider if that's what you want.

Comment: It isn't what I want (I think!!!). I want implement an exact copy of "Facebook connect": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827997/is-facebook-an-openid-provider.

Comment: If they're all subdomains of the same domain, you don't need any such system at all. Set cookie domain `.example.com` and you're done.

Comment: have you tried https://www.myopenid.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook is using OAuth 2.0 and this is now more popular than openid. You can see how to implement it on [railcasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=oauth) or search for "oauth rails" and you will geht enough info about it.

In my opinion this is the thing you are looking for.