# Is facebook an openid provider?

Tags: facebook, openid, google-openid, openid-provider

I'm confused about facebook and whether or not facebook is an openid provider like google.

According to this link: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/246/, facebook is an openid  relying party.  What does that mean, and is that different from an openid provider like google.

Basically, I am currently using lightopenid to allow users to use their openid's to log into my site, but can't seem to find a url for facebook's openid authentication to do this.

**I have seen a question similar to this which confuses me because in that question, the questioner was told that facebook is not an openid provider, yet facebook documentation says something that facebook is a openid relying party...???**

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827997/is-facebook-an-openid-provider

Comment: The question does look the same, but it does not answer the bold part in my question.

Comment: I think that the other question does contain the answer. Facebook ACCEPT openId logins, but do NOT act as a provider, just a consumer: "Facebook is not an OpenID provider, they do however allow OpenID login using Google accounts."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook is an OAuth provider. You need to use OAuth if you want to allow Facebook users to authenticate against your service.

Being an OpenID Relying Party means that Facebook accepts OpenID logins from their users, e.g. you can log in to Facebook with your Google account. Your service is also a Relying Party if it allows users to authenticate using their OpenIDs.

For more information on the terminology used by OpenID, see [the OpenID Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#Technical_Overview).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that is exactly what I did not get by reading the apparent duplicate question.